# Including entire services directory

Tags: ros, ros2, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a srv directory that has all the services I have created. In my main node I am including each individual .hpp manually. Is there a way to include all the .hpp files in one include statement, or do I need to do it for each individual service I created?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329803/including-entire-services-directory/) by [mikepark93](https://answers.ros.org/users/44418/mikepark93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, C++ does not allow that.

However, you may create a file named `my_services.hpp` with all the includes.

```
#pragma once

#include "srv_pkg/srv/service_1"
#include "srv_pkg/srv/service_2"
#include "srv_pkg/srv/service_3"
#include "srv_pkg/srv/service_4"
```

Then in all the places where you need to use the services you can just use `#include "my_services.hpp"`.

An alternative would be to use a script to automatically add all the include directives to your files, but I really think that's a bad and error-prone solution.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1